# React: Eslint fix remove prop name={name} from jsx

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier, eslintrc

There's eslint errors when the linter auto fix errors it removes the `{name}` from `name={name}`

- eslint error that trying to fix : `Function component is not a function expressioneslintreact/function-component-definition`
- Befor lint fix :

```js
export default ({
    className,
    label,
    value,
    setValue,
    name,
    readOnly,
}) => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className={className}>
                <div className="mb-2 grey-i">
                   <label>{label}</label>
                    <CheckboxField
                        name={name}
                        label={label}
                        readOnly={readOnly}
                        value={value}
                        setValue={setValue} />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

- After lint fix :

```js
  export default function({
    className,
    label,
    value,
    setValue,
    name,
    readOnly,
}) {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className={className}>
                <div className="mb-2 grey-i">
                   <label>{label}</label>
                    <CheckboxField
                        name=
                        label={label}
                        readOnly={readOnly}
                        value={value}
                        setValue={setValue} />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

This only happen with prop `name={name}` only

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do and what error you are getting, could improve your question? Also, try not including code as images.

Comment: should be clear now and i've removed the image , thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing this behaviour, but after reading the documentation of the rule I would try naming the function to see if the error persists.